# How should i choose my hosting service for Laravel Apps?

Tags: laravel-5, web-applications, hosting, web-hosting

I have my Laravel 5 app hosted on a shared hosting service. From the beginning i saw that was a bad idea, but i didn't knew more and i leaved it that way.

Now, i need a new hosting service that can give me SSH access for using git, jenkins, run laravel commands and a good speed.(I live in est Europe).

I've made some research i found 3 hosting services: Amazon, A2hosting and Siteground.

Because i'm not a very experimented developer and my app is not that big (and i don't think it will be in the next 1-2 years) , i think choosing Amazon's services will be an overhead.Plus that, i think it will be pretty expensive.

So, what should i choose between those 3 options?
Or do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you app is not that big AWS is a great option for you. They have free tier where I am running my instance with Laravel App. Its not as expensive as it looks.

Check their calculator if you want more than free tier which is explained here https://aws.amazon.com/free/.

Calculator: https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html